# How can I get the detailed info of each API call in an ASP.NET web API application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure

To be specific, I have an ASP.NET web API application running on Azure, and I hope to monitor it and log the detailed info into the database, i.e., HTTP response code, duration, calls per second, etc., whenever an API call happens.

I know there are some tools which can help trace the performance, dotTrace, for instance. However, I'm unable to get their source code.

Also, I know that writing codes using Action Filter & Performance Counter can satisfy my needs to some extent, but it seems that I can not get the detailed info of each API call by the using two.

My final goal: have the log info stored in the database and info(bottlenecks, exceptions and anomalies) can be emailed to me automatically on a weekly basis.

Many thanks if you could help.

Comment: There's also Application Insights - http://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/services/application-insights/

Comment: Thank you so much! Great tool.